# Using fields in a csv file as variable in sge array job - awk

Tags: bash, awk, sungridengine

I can use the following bash script to assign a variable ID from each line (first 1000 lines in this case) of the ids file and run it as argument to pythonscript.py.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -t 1:1000
#$ -N thename
#$ -j y

ids=NOBACK/ids.txt
echo "Starting on : $(date)"
echo "Running on node : $(hostname)"
echo "Current directory : $(pwd)"
echo "Current job ID : $JOB_ID"
echo "Current job name : $JOB_NAME"
echo "Task index number : $SGE_TASK_ID"
ID=`awk "NR==$SGE_TASK_ID" {IDS}` 
echo "id is: $ID"
python pythonscript.py --idarg ID
echo "Finished on : $(date)"
```

But if the file is a csv file and I need to assign multiple variables, how it could be done?

Comment: Could you add a few more details? When you say "multiple variables", do you mean you'd like your CSV file to be of the form `job_number, value1,value2,value3`?

Comment: Also, what does IDS in the awk script refer to? Should the ID variable in the call to python be $ID?

Comment: Yes, sure. I've missed the IDS variable assignment line. Just corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have the following csv file (named super.csv):

```
 name,postcode,dob
 alan,XXXAAA,11/11/55
 bruji,AAAXXX,20/10/88
 ...
 zorri,AXAXAX,01/01/01
```

and you want to use the first and third fields as arguments in your sungrid engine array job.
The following will extract the fields from the lane equals to the $SGE_TASK_ID:

```
NAME=$(awk -F, -v "line=$SGE_TASK_ID" 'NR==line {print $1}' super.csv)
DOB=$(awk -F, -v "line=$SGE_TASK_ID" 'NR==line {print $3}' super.csv)
```

I was messing with double and single quotes. The bash will ignore $ var within single quotes and extend variables within double quotes. Here -v is injecting the $SGE_TASK_ID variable to awk scope (within single quotes).